# How to register new consumer after starting rabbitmq ioloop?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I am experimenting with pika API for rabbitmq and am observing a weird bahaviour. I have three threads.

**Thread 1**: Creates new queues and produces messages using a thread specific connection *conn1*. All messages get routed to all queues.

**Thread 2**: Instantiates SelectConnection - *conn2* and a channel *chan1*

**Thread 3**: In a loop calls *chan1.basic_consume()* for each queue created by thread 1. Each queue has a unique message handler. (one message consumer per queue)

When I see the output I find that last message handler is handling messages from all the queues.

How do I ensure that the handlers for different consumers don't get overwritten ? Is this because I am calling *basic_consume()* from a separate thread or because I am calling it after calling *ioloop.start()* ?

I can paste the code here if required.